# If you know someone's ethereum address do you effectively know their balance?

Tags: balances

Let's say someone pays you, can't they figure out your balance since the ledger is exposed to the public?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ethereum is fully transparent. With ZK-Snarks coming soon, that could very well change though.